# Javascript: Input value on fields and show value on popup

Tags: javascript, python, mysql, django

I have a registration form. After filling up the forms, the reference number will display in popup. A reminder for the user to use for logging in the system.

*register.html*

```
<div>Reference No.<input type="text" name="refno" value="{{ refno }}" readonly></div>
<div>Name<input type="text" name="name"></div>
...
<button type="submit" id="getInputValue()" class="btn">Submit</button>
```

this is my script

```
function getInputValue() {
  let textElement = document.getElementById('refno').value;
  alert(textElement);
```

*views.py*

```
if request.method == 'GET':
    random_chars = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits, k=8))
    refno = f"{random_chars}"
    return render(request, 'registration_form.html', {"refno": refno})
if request.method == 'POST':
    refno = request.POST.get('refno')
    name = request.POST.get('name')
    ...
    Applicant.objects.create(refno=refno, name=name, ...)
    return redirect(/user_login/)
```

So after the button was clicked, the msg should display the reference number before it proceed to the login form. So I'm a bit confused on how to show the popup first before login. If I write `return render(request, 'registration_form.html')`, it will just return to the form. With this code I have, it doesn't even show a pop up. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show reference number in login page. So, use `django messages` to do it.

```
from django import messages

if request.method == 'POST':
   refno = request.POST.get('refno')
   name = request.POST.get('name')
   ...
   Applicant.objects.create(refno=refno, name=name, ...)
   messages.success(request, f'{refno}')
   return redirect(/user_login/)
```

For showing messages in template with popup:

```
{% if messages %}
     {% for message in messages %}
        <div>Reference No.<input type="text" name="refno" value="{{ message }}" readonly></div>
        <div>Name<input type="text" name="name"></div>
        ...
        <button type="submit" id="getInputValue()" class="btn">Submit</button>
     {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I tried this one and it displays the reference number. Thank you so much!